# Multiline parsing in Fluent-Bit for Java running on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I am attempting to get fluent-bit multiline logs working for my apps running on kubernetes. These are java springboot applications. Is there a way to send the logs through the docker parser (so that they are formatted in json), and then use a custom multiline parser to concatenate the logs that are broken up by `\n`? I am attempting to use the date format as the start of the multiline parser, and am starting off with `This.*` to capture the next line that should be included in the first log, rather than broken up into different events. I am also using the default kubernetes filter for the logs. Here are the config files with the input, filter, and parsers:

```
    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Path                /var/log/containers/test-container*
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        Rotate_Wait         30
        storage.type        filesystem
        Read_from_Head      On

    [FILTER]
        Name                  multiline
        Match                 application.*
        multiline.key_content log
        multiline.parser      docker, multi_docker_java

    [MULTILINE_PARSER]
        name                      multi_docker_java
        type                      regex
        flush_timeout             1000
        key_content               log
        rule      "start_state"   "/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z.*"           "cont"
        rule      "cont"          "/This.*"                                                      "cont"

    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               application.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     application.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Labels              Off
        Annotations         Off
        Use_Kubelet         On
        Kubelet_Port        10250
        Buffer_Size         0
```

The log I am testing with is below (kubernetes info is being included but not shown here):

```
{
    "log": "2023-05-05T13:46:47.628Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.e.sampleApp.controller.MainController  : This is line one of the log message.\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "",
        "namespace_name": "",
        "pod_id": "",
        "host": "",
        "container_name": "",
        "docker_id": "",
        "container_hash": "",
        "container_image": ""
    }
}


{
    "log": "This is line two of the log message.\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "",
        "namespace_name": "",
        "pod_id": "",
        "host": "",
        "container_name": "",
        "docker_id": "",
        "container_hash": "",
        "container_image": ""
    }
}


{
    "log": "Here I am!\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "",
        "namespace_name": "",
        "pod_id": "",
        "host": "",
        "container_name": "",
        "docker_id": "",
        "container_hash": "",
        "container_image": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: i got the above issue resolved by removing the filter and specifying the mutline parsers directly in the input block. i am now having an issue where i am not able to continue on a log like that is only `\n`. i have tried multiple regex commands for the "cont" block, but cannot get it to include that line in the "start_state" finding

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing how the parsers actually work in Fluentbit.

You will need to have your `conf` in 1 file but your `parsers` in another eg.

```
# fluentbit.conf
[SERVICE]
    Parsers_File /path/to/parsers.conf

...

[FILTER]
    name                  multiline
    match                 *
    multiline.key_content log
    multiline.parser      go, multiline-regex-test

...
```

and then

```
# /path/to/parsers.conf

[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-regex-test
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 1000
    #
    # Regex rules for multiline parsing
    # ---------------------------------
    #
    # configuration hints:
    #
    #  - first state always has the name: start_state
    #  - every field in the rule must be inside double quotes
    #
    # rules |   state name  | regex pattern                  | next state
    # ------|---------------|--------------------------------------------
    rule      "start_state"   "/(Dec \d+ \d+\:\d+\:\d+)(.*)/"  "cont"
    rule      "cont"          "/^\s+at.*/"                     "cont"
```

See [multiline-stacktrace Docs](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/multiline-stacktrace).

**Note**: The screenshot below shows tabs for each configuration file required

[image: Screenshot of the Fluentbit multiline-stacktrace docs]

---

Looking at your actual parser. If you are trying to parse the following logs:

```
2023-05-05T13:46:47.628Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.e.sampleApp.controller.MainController  : This is line one of the log message
something else
hello
2023-05-05T13:47:00.132Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.e.sampleApp.controller.MainController  : This is line one of the log message.
```

Once way you can achieve this is using a positive and negitive search pattern for your multiline parser eg.

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
        name                      multi_docker_java
        type                      regex
        flush_timeout             1000
        key_content               log
        rule      "start_state"   "/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z.*/"  "cont"
        rule      "cont"          "/^(?!\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T).+/"  "cont"
```

Comment: I have them in different files, but just included them side by side to show the config

Comment: I've updated my question. But it looks like you're missing the trailing `/` in your regex rules.

Comment: Note: (?!<regex>) is a negative lookahead that will Assert that the Regex below does not match